# MOV failed due to lighting or OV on power line Feeder control

Tags: fuses, surge-protection, over-voltage-protection, lightning, mov

we have a filed failure of our product which is feeder controller as shown in below image. It installed in metal box. we have tested our feeder stand alone at 15KV surge and it compliance with 15KV. But we also added one external SPD to get more surge protection. last month customer reported approx. 35 feeder burnet out in line. we have checked all feeder and found MOV2, Fuse and L1 all are burn. and MOV1 was fine. customer reported lightening happed in that area usually.

[image]

[image]
But I guess if this is because if lightening than we have protection till 15KV.

Q1) it should protect my feeder from failure. Why is not protecting ?

Q2) If Surge was above 15KAV than it should fail SPD first rather than Feeder. Right?

I guess there can be a temporary over voltage condition on line due to that MOV 2 and fuse got burnet. my Feeder is sealed pack unit, even I single component failed we need to to RMA and replace the unit. Is there any solution externally I can add like Over voltage cut off device (OVCD), I search on internet but couldn't find any reliable OVCD. Please advise

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the box SPD does nothing. The second hypothesis is that there was no lightning strike involved at all. The first MOV1 didn't conduct, neither SPD, only the 2nd MOV2 has conducted because the mains voltage raised to more than 320VAC. And this was not just a 8/20us lightning pulse.

In my opinion, those devices were connected to three phase system 3P+PEN 400VAC and the neutral got missing. Your apparatus got 400VAC, so that's why the MOV2 failed without the other lightning protection. The customer is a liar.

Comment: So any device suggest which can be installed with feeder to protect from this type of issue.

Comment: @4MhzCrystal A crowbar circuit, it's similar to triac AC dimmer. But you won't find these in regular products, it makes sense that connecting a 230VAC device to 400VAC it will smoke.

Answer (score 0):

This has the symptoms of MOV failure from overvoltage.

The root cause is unknown with insufficient details.

To protect the protection a thermally compensated or fused MOV and crowbar may be used to trip the MOV and then the breaker respectively from sustained OV due to a lightning interruption.

If this Line is under-loaded relative to the other 2 lines of a 3 phase network then transient OV is more likely to occur upon grid reclosure. Then load balancing must be performed by the customer.

Comment: So any device suggest which can be installed with feeder to protect from this type of issue

Comment: No on p/n , answer already given for type of protection to search for. And inquire about load unbalance.